# Is it a bad idea to construct mongodb query in front-end?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In the frontend, stringify below

```
{ options: { $or: [ id1, id2, id3 ], foo: { $gte: bar} } }
```

And in the backend

Use that directly in `SomeCol.Find(req.params.options)`

Of course  with validation/sanitization

**Edit**

I was planning to whitelist what user can query in the backend

```
// pseudo validator schema
{
  $or: isArrayOf({ _id: MongoId }),
  foo: isObject({
    $gte: isNumber()
  })
}
```

If query from front-end does not meet that schema, it stops there.
And since I'm always running `find()` for `GET Method` (so not inserting), I thought this would be convenient.

Still sketchy?

Comment: Doing this means that clients can run ANY queries against that collection. You decide, whether it's a problem for you or not.

Comment: Still sketchy and not recommended, but it's your code and your responsibility. You will find endless recommendations against this from and architecture and security POV.

Comment: No prob, it sounds like you want to build up dynamic queries which can easily be done, just rather build them up manually in the backend using validated data and fields you define so you are confident they queries are safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most definitely. You do not want your clients to be able to run any queries against your collection. This would open up Pandora's box and put your data at extreme risk.

You need to encapsulate the implementation details as much as possible to help keep your system secure and extensible.

All data coming into your system must be scrutinized and validated to avoid injection attacks.